# Why my iPhone app cannot call the delegate method

Tags: iphone, ios, navigationbar, titleview

I'm developing the iPhone app. I custom defined the titleview for navigation bar. The title view contains a button, I also defined the delegate method to support the button click event. But when the button clicked, the delegate cannot be executed. I am not sure why ?
Below as my codes:
UPDelegate.h

```
@protocol UPDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)buttonClick;
@end
```

TitleView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UPDelegate.h"
@interface TitleView :UIView
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id<UPDelegate> delegate;
-(id)initWithCustomTitleView;
@end
```

TitleView.m

```
@synthesize delegate;
-(id)initWithCustomTitleView
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        UIButton *titleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIBUttonTypeCustom];
        titleButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 44);
        [titleButton setTitle:@"ABC" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // add action
        [titleButton addTarget:delegate action:@selector(buttonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:titleButton];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In my ViewController, i implement the protocal as below:

MyViewController.h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UPDelegate>
```

and in the .m file, i wrote the delegate method, but cannot be exeucte.
MyViewController.m

```
-(void)buttonClick{
    NSLog("click title button");
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the delegate?

Comment: Where are you "setting" the delegate to your MyViewController?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your `delegate`, from you code sample you are creating `id<UPDelegate> delegate;` in your `titleView` class.

So in your `MyViewController` where you have added `<UPDelegate>`, create an instance of `TitleView` and set delegate to self.

So in your `MyViewController` use:

```
 TitleView*titleView=[[TitleView alloc]init];
 titleView.delegate=self;
```

Comment: I already added 'titleView.delegate = self' in my codes, but forgot the parse to the question. And the delegate method still cannot be executed

Comment: @user429079 Try adding `-(void)buttonClick;` in your `.h`, and check where command+click on `<UPDelegate>` takes you in `MyViewController`. And where have you set `delegate=self`?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have not set the value of your titleView's delegate property, so any messages sent to the delegate property are ignored because the delegate is nil.

You should make sure that you are setting your titleView's delegate to be your MyViewController.  The best place to do this is most likely in your MyViewController's `viewDidLoad:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the delegate anywhere? Because you have to set the delegate of your TitleView to MyViewController:

```
titleView.delegate = self;
```